# Strange behaviour when using BlendMode "erase" in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can any one expain how to avoid seeing lines when using BlendMode.ERASE in AS3?

Here is an example. I draw a black background to the stage and then draw 2 overlaping circles to a sprite and try to erase them from the background.

```
            var solidBitmapData = new BitmapData(550,400,true,0x000000);
            var mySpriteLayer = new Sprite();

            // Create black background.
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.drawRect(0,0,550,400);
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.endFill();

            // Draw it to bitmap data.
            solidBitmapData.draw(mySpriteLayer);

            // Clear sprite.
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.clear();

            // Draw two circles
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.drawCircle(200,200,50);
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.endFill();
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.drawCircle(250,200,50);
            mySpriteLayer.graphics.endFill();

            // Draw circles to bitmap with blend mode erase.
            solidBitmapData.draw(mySpriteLayer,null,null,BlendMode.ERASE);

            // Create bitmap and add to stage.
            var solidBitmap = new Bitmap(solidBitmapData);
            addChild(solidBitmap);
```

[image: Lines shown here]

I'm talking about the lines in the middle of the circles. It seems to be something to do with linestyle but I've tried setting it to zero and the alpha to 0 but I can't get rid of the lines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `cacheAsBitmap` property of '`mySpriteLayer`' to '`true`' :

```
     mySpriteLayer.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

As blend mode performs computations on pixels, it works more precisely with raster data, than with vector data.

Comment: Perfect. I was sure I had tried that, but must have missed it because it worked perfectly.

Comment: any insight on why that actually makes it work? i think that's one of the most inobvious fixes i've ever seen :D

Comment: @divillysausages Check again my answer.

Comment: @user1113426 yeah, i wasn't understanding that. `draw()`ing turns it into raster, and using a `BlendMode` does the same, so I didn't see how rastering it *again* made it work :) Makes sense now I suppose

Comment: Thanks - this fixed a similar issue for me

Comment: Thanks , my same problem get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
```

Adobe's ActionScript 3.0 Reference says about class BlendMode and field ERASE:

> Erases the background based on the alpha value of the display object.
>   This process requires that the blendMode property of the parent
>   display object be set to flash.display.BlendMode.LAYER.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the way the Sprite blend is reacting to the background. Have you tried this with two black circles on a white background? If you get the same lines (only white) you are able to conclude this is the way the blend works.